# How to display smooth movement of current location in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I am implementing a map navigation application. I get device's current location every 1000 milliseconds and draw a polyline, from the current location to fixed marker point. But when using device inside a vehicle, polyline and current location update not animating like uber or google-map. It's changing suddenly from one point to another.

How to get a smooth animation of the current location change.

Comment: You can't display more precisely than 1s. In your case you may need to extrapolate the position by calculating the speed and the direction. It may exist a lib that do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to try this way it will help you

```
private void animateMarkerNew(final LatLng startPosition, final LatLng destination, final Marker marker) {

        if (marker != null) {

            final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude);

            final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
            final LatLngInterpolatorNew latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolatorNew.LinearFixed();

            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(2000); // duration 3 second
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    try {
                        float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                        LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(newPosition)
                                .zoom(18f)
                                .build()));

                        marker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition, new LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //I don't care atm..
                    }
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                    // if (mMarker != null) {
                    // mMarker.remove();
                    // }
                    // mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_car)));

                }
            });
            valueAnimator.start();
        }
    }
```

Note: marker is mean which marker you want to animate that one.

```
 private interface LatLngInterpolatorNew {
        LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

        class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolatorNew {
            @Override
            public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
                double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
                double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;
                // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
                if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                    lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
                }
                double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
                return new LatLng(lat, lng);
            }
        }
    }
```

//Method for finding bearing between two points

```
private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

    if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
    else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think this animate one point to another point randomly in any one direction, It doesn't care about path.. I want to animate through path. Is it possible?

Comment: You saying path mean polylines right, polyline have a lat and long, here starting position is your marker position, destination point is your next polyline, then pass use marker object. Hope it will work

Comment: @Raja I think he's correct as this solution may work on straight polylines but it doesn't work on the hashmap path or roads we get from google to show route between two points.

Comment: in this marker gets disappear after some time how to solve this

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran - had you managed to fix the marker disappearing issue?